# Using Javascript to change the background-position CSS - small problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Probably an easy question here (I hope) but my brain's just stopped working.

I have this javascript:

```
       value.obj.css('background-position', value.xStart + 10)
```

which changes the background-position of my object by 10 in the x direction.

However I also want to be able to change the position in the y direction but in a different amount (ie, 40). the code being "value.yStart + 40"

Background-position in css is written like "background-position: 30 30;". When I use the above javascript to change it, it comes out "background-position: 40 50%;" but I want it to be "background-position: 40 70;" Please help... been a long day :)

Comment: what js library are you using?

Comment: Are you using a framework? `.css(...)` doesn't strike me as a standard JS function.

Comment: You need to use a measurement when defining css properties. Otherwise, if you have `background-position: 30 30;` the browser doesn't know what the 30 is. Is it px? Is it em? If you're using a JS framework it might handle this automatically, but you'll need to check the API documentation to be sure.

Comment: Ooops, forgot to mention that I am using jQuery. This does handle it automatically, making it px (I assume it is because the original amount in the style sheet is in px for both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
value.obj.css({ 'background-position': (value.xStart + 10) + 'px ' + (value.yStart + 40) + 'px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well dont tell people how [`background-position`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp) works, because you got it a little wrong.

Either you use `%` or `px`:
so:

```
 background-position: 30px 30px;
 //or:
 background-position: 30px 30%;
 //or even:
 background-position: 30% 30%;
```

Comment: Sorry yeah I forgot to mention the 'px', but I didnt think that was relevant to my question because regardless of if it is px, em or percentages the problem is passing in two values into the background-position. Currently it is passing in only one (which works correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it must be `backgroundPosition` (all css properties are camel cased in jquery), and in your case it should be:

`.css('backgroundPosition', '30px 30px')`

or

`.css({ 'backgroundPosition': '30px 30px' })`

Comment: Strangely enough, it's actually working with .css('background-position', '30px 30px')

Comment: You are right, I checked it in the docs that both ways are supported http://api.jquery.com/css/.